# tablet similar to iPad mini with Android , does it exist?

Tags: android, tablet, apple

I am looking for a tablet, relatively small, with nice stylus, and it seems the only option is the iPad.

With Android, small Samsungs and Lenovos are a joke (also cost like what they cost, true), and as soon as you look for something with good stylus (not crappy compatible things that you must keep the palm away from the screen) and nice screen resolution (really, 800p in 2022 is not good). Shop-sellers point me to only 10 inches and bigger.

I will even accept a windows tablet :-(

Note: I am not asking for a recommendation which is best (i got offtopic in Android forum), but to know even this tablet exist. I cant figure out how the plenty of Android manufactures that exist, no-one have thought of a iPad mini format.

Comment: Very interesting, there are indeed not a lot of small tablets and the ones that are seem to be iPads.

Comment: If it´s only about OS, have read that it is posible to put android on iPad.

Comment: You can get a refurbished Note 9 for cheap. It's stylus is great!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... small-screen Android tablets are unfortunately all low end.

I think the **[Samsung Galaxy Tab Active3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08T7V27QJ)** is the only kid in town. But it's a ruggedized tablet, so it might not be suitable for you.

Something else to consider - though it goes into a new category - is a Microsoft Surface Duo/Surface Duo 2 or Samsung Galaxy Z Fold (2/3).

- They support styluses (Surface Slim Pen & S Pen respectively)
- Have similar (but smaller) size screen when unfolded (8.1" & 7.6"
  respectively.)
- Pretty high-end specs (but a price even higher...)

Comment: I like the idea of the foldable phones as tablets and phones at once, less devices, less ewaste, less poisinous stuff in the country where its made (sorry, Im reading the story of stuff...)